# JQuery script working in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

I'm building a library to save watched series and I'm struggling with some sort of incompatibility with my JQuery script.
It works as intended in Chrome and Edge but not in Firefox.
The reason of this script is to populate a div with content.

```
    <script>
  jQuery(document).on('submit', '.seasons_form', function(e){  
  event.preventDefault();

$.ajax({

type: "POST",
url: $(this).attr("action"),
data: $(this).serialize(),

success:function(data){
;


    document.getElementById("chapters_container").innerHTML = (data);

},
error:function(xhr,exception)
{

}
})
e.preventDefault();
  });

</script>
```

In Firefox it redirects me to the function I'm calling instead of populating the div.
I have read several similar problems here but I can not find the solution.

Is anyone able to help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use e.preventDefault() not event.preventDefault() because you named your event argument "e"

Comment: I'm hoping the `error:function()` isn't actually blank in the code you're using.  Letting errors fall through the cracks like this is really bad practice.  At a minimum, you should be doing an alert out to the user to let them know something didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the event variable with your function in FireFox, such as:

```
jQuery(document).on('submit', '.seasons_form', function(event) {}
```

It is a global variable in IE and Chrome etc. but not in FF.
As a result you need to pass it explicitly.